# ionic run android - configurations not running app on device

Tags: android, debugging, ionic-framework, adb

I am trying to build and debug **`ionic 2 app`** on my android devices.
Following are the details of console out put when am trying to run command **`ionic run android`**

```
#->ionic run android

∆ Compiling Sass to CSS
√ Matching patterns: app/theme/app.+(ios|md).scss

∆ Copying fonts
√ Matching patterns: node_modules/ionic-framework/fonts/**/*.+(ttf|woff|woff2)

∆ Copying HTML
√ Matching patterns: app/**/*.html

∆ Compiling and bundling with Webpack...
√ Using your webpack.config.js file
√ Sass compilation complete
√ HTML copied to www/build
√ Fonts copied to www/build/fonts
√ Compiling files complete.

Hash: 3239d7653edd2f88c126
Version: webpack 1.12.10
Time: 6745ms
        Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
app.bundle.js  2.68 MB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] multi main 64 bytes {0} [built]
    + 362 hidden modules

√ Webpack complete

#->
```

My app **`Androidmanifest.xml`** contains:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

And when I am running following **`adb devices`** command I can see device is attached.

```
List of devices attached
5b234380    device
```

Following is the screenshot of packages installed in **`Android SDK Manager`**:

[image: Screenshot of Android SDK Manager 1]
[image: Screenshot of Android SDK Manager 2]
[image: Screenshot of Android SDK Manager 3]

Also this is the `informations` of my `ionic` system:

```
#->ionic info

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 4.3.1
Ionic Version: 2.0.0-beta.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.17
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.8
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v5.3.0
Xcode version: Not installed


******************************************************
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,      
 it is highly suggested to install/upgrade the following:     

 Install ios-sim to deploy iOS applications. `npm install -g ios-sim` (may require sudo)
 Install ios-deploy to deploy iOS applications to devices. `npm install -g ios-deploy` (may require sudo)

******************************************************
```

I just want to run on android device right now, so `ios-sim` and `ios-deploy` packages are not installed.

---

**`Update`**
When I try to run to add platform android, it saying already exist:

```
#->ionic  platform add android
Running command: /Users/Piccaza/ionic-projects/fobs-v0.9.9/hooks/before_platform_add/init_directories.js /Users/Piccaza/ionic-projects/fobs-v0.9.9
Platform android already added.
```

---

what might be the issue here, so that I am not able to run the app on device? I am kind of stuck for 2 days please help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just `ionic run android` I tried with `sudo`, as follows:

> **`sudo ionic run android`**

And app started running in  device.

NOTE: ionic wont show any error or waring if we just execute the command:
**`ionic run android`**